# Cannot build my project after updating to Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently upgraded to Android Studio 4.2. I can no longer build my project.

Android Studio non-stop trying to start `Gradle Daemon`, but cannot do so:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 5 s 92 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 406 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 968 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 937 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
```

I think as a result of this, dozens of `OpenJDK Platform binaries` are being generated in my `TaskManager`. This processes never stops until my machine runs out of memory. In such cases, very frequently, Android Studio is crashing.

[image]

When I do get to point where Android Studio stops building, it shows me an error: (I am sorry I am posting error image. My laptop is frozen that it is not possible to copy the error message.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Studio tries to import previous .vmoptions and sanitize them to work
> with the garbage collector used by JDK 11. If that process fails, the
> IDE may not start for certain users who set custom VM options in the
> .vmoptions file.

In order to resolve this problem, try:

> We recommend commenting out custom options in .vmoptions (using the
> “#” character). The .vmoptions file can be found in the following
> locations:
>
> Windows
>
> C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData[Local|Roaming]\Google\AndroidStudio4.2\studio64.exe.vmoptions

Check out the docs for more known issues of Android Studio 4.2 https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Answer (score 0):

Try opening build.gradle and there at the top you will see JDK not recognized dialog click on it and choose your JDK. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Potential solutions:

**Solution 1.**

Restart your machine. Then re-open your project. It should fix the issues.

**Solution 2.**

It is possible that Android Studio 4.2 is having issues due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin

Go to these folders:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google
```

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google
```

Find `Android Studio 4.1` or similar directory of previous version of Android Studio. Delete (or rename, for backup purposes) the directory, depending on the Android Studio version, and start Android Studio again.